# Synchronize two objects with different types

Tags: c#, object, synchronization

I have two classes which possess number of the same properties and each one has some that are not shared by the other.

What would be the fastest way to sync shared properties of two object ? I know it could be easily done via reflection but I bet somewhere in the framework there is some goody that can make this process one liner or so.

Thx.

Comment: Please add your programming language.

Comment: Could both classes share common ancestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that there aren't *goodies* in the framework to do this process a one-liner. There's [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) though which could be used for this task.